# php loop in a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

How to do a for loop in a while loop , as the coding below. The table need to show a list of number of how many data columm had got in the

```
       <?php

        $server = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "");
        $db =  mysql_select_db("registration",$server);
        $query = mysql_query("select * from user");
    ?>
    <table class="striped">
        <tr class="header">
            <td>No</td>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Title</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
           while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                for($x =1 ; $x <= $row ; $x++);
               echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td>"'$x'"</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row['password']."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row['position']."</td>";
               echo "</tr>";
           }

        ?>## Heading ##
```

Comment: **Waring:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$count = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $count . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['position'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    ++$count;
}
```

## OR

```
$count = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $count++ . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['position'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?php
               $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
               echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<td> Total Rows".$num_rows."</td>";
               echo "</tr>";
               $i = 1;
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                    echo "<tr>";              
                   echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row['password']."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row['position']."</td>";
                   echo "</tr>";
                   $i++;
               }
?>
```